# How to compute spin projections in QE?

Tags: quantum-espresso, spin-orbit-coupling, spin, spin-polarization

It's well known that VASP can print three orthogonal spin projections at each k point corresponding to each band in the file [PROCAR](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/PROCAR) controlled by the tags [LORBIT](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/LORBIT) and [RWIGS](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/RWIGS). Is there a way
to obtain the same information from calculations done by QE?

This problem is also discussed [here](https://lists.quantum-espresso.org/pipermail/users/2022-March/048896.html).

Regards,
HZ

Answer (score 2):

If you do a noncollinear calculation, you can then get the spin projections along the x, y and z axes by utilizing the post-processing executable `pp.x` and choosing `plot_num=7` and `spin_component=1/2/3`.
You can see other options in the [input documentation](https://www.quantum-espresso.org/Doc/INPUT_PP.html#idm22).

Answer (score 1):

I noticed [the following answer](https://lists.quantum-espresso.org/pipermail/users/2022-March/048904.html) on QE mail list from [Thomas Brumme](https://scholar.google.ru/citations?user=bmIgwLYAAAAJ&hl=en), which is inconsistent with the answer suggested by Maxim-s:

> Dear Luiz,
>
> the correct tool you search is bands.x - if you look at the
> description of it, you will find the key word
>
> lsigma(i), i=1,3 which does the job. Usually, bands.x is used for
> paths along high symmetry lines in the BZ but you can also provide a
> full MP grid if you want to plot the spin texture in the whole BZ. I
> actually did this for a manuscript which is in the
> still-to-be-finalized stage since ages...
>
> Kind regards
>
> Thomas

Comment: Please click "edit" and then click the box that says "community wiki".  The reason why I ask this is because you're pasting an answer that was mostly written by Thomas (not yourself), so it's a "community answer", not an individual answer.

Comment: I can't find the box that says "community wiki".

Comment: It was completed for you yestrrday :)

Comment: But I still don't understand how exactly you do it.